# How do I use .data() when creating controls dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-3.5, dynamic-controls

I am creating a user control that will create a series of html elements dynamically. Some of these controls will be database-driven cascading drop-downs. I've seen the JQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method suggested and used in examples for storing additional data about controls, but I don't know how to implement it on dynamically created elements.

I'm adding elements this way:

```
new LiteralControl(@"<select onchange=""DoSomething()""></select>")
```

So, how do I go about using .data() on these newly created elements so that the additional data is stored when they're created? I wanted to use custom attributes, but I gather that's not widely supported and can be problematic in legacy browsers.

I am very new to web stuff, so by all means if I didn't explain something well, let me know.

Comment: How about just adding `data-foo="bar"` attributes?

Comment: @zerkms I was under the impression that custom attributes aren't supported until html-5 and that some legacy browsers will complain.

Comment: Custom attributes work in pretty much all browsers in use these days, even including ten-year-old versions of IE, though it's best to use html5 `data-xzy` attributes. (Officially, custom attributes may be "invalid", but that doesn't mean they won't work.)

Comment: @Yatrix: I've never heard of any browser "complaining" about invalid attributes. In this respect, HTML5 is just trying to *rein in* what people were already doing.

Comment: Well, if the SO community says it's cool, it must be. I was using those anyway, but I thought it was going to be a problem. Thanks all!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it the way I asked?

Comment: @Yatrix: Anything you can write a selector for, you can use `data` on client-side. I can't help you with doing it prior to that. This sounds like just what `data-*` attributes are for. The alternative would be to give the element an `id` or `class` which you then use instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fair enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish with `.data()`?  You've essentially asked a question like "How do I use a hammer?", but not told us what problem you're trying to solve with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which data the elements should store by the time you are creating those elements, you could use `data-*` attributes.

```
new LiteralControl(@"<select data-id="1" onchange=""DoSomething()""></select>")
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but you're the only one that responded and it does solve my problem. =)

Comment: That's definitely the way to go

Comment: What do you want use data() for if you are generating the data on the server-side?